# How do I trace the root cause error when Botbuilder throws the default error message?

Tags: node.js, botframework

[image: Conversation showing the issue]

I've deployed a node.js chatbot (built using Microsoft Botbuilder package) as an Azure web app. As seen in the attached image, the conversation in channel emulator(same with web chat) goes on smoothly until there's a db call. The part were the intent handler tries to do db call, the bot responds with the default error text(I didn't understand. Please try again.).

Interestingly, if I type in something random( like a Hello) in response followed by the query again, the bot goes ahead with the db call. This scenario is shown in the attached screenshot.

Strangely, the issue doesn't happen when I work on the bot locally or deploy it outside Azure (say AWS).

My question is how do I figure out what exactly is going wrong here ? I have been going through the logs in the Diagnostic Console(Kudu) of my Azure web app, but no pointers in any of the logs. Any help is appreciated!

**edit:** Got it fixed by following the steps from this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/2859)

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the error?

Comment: @NilsW thanks for your time. Got it fixed by following the steps from [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/2859).